# Show all posts in a custom post type on a taxonomy archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, archive, taxonomy

I want to redirect my taxonomy archive pages to the main archive page for the post type, displaying all the posts and then filtering them rather than only displaying only the ones matching the taxonomy term. I believe I need to alter the loop using pre_get_posts but I can't remove the taxonomy. I have tried:

```
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tax()) {
        $query->set( 'tax_query',array() ); 
}

if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tax()) {
        $query->set( 'tax_query','' );  
}
```

I've read solutions for changing tax_query, but not removing it.

Alternatively, is there a better way to redirect a taxonomy archive to a post type archive? (I've searched for this but found nothing.)

Comment: To be clear – you're looking to 1) __redirect the user__ (send a `301` response), or 2) alter the content of the taxonomy url to look like the main archive page? I think #1 is preferable!

Comment: Whatever works to be honest! I was trying to redirect as well but that still pulled through the loop for just the taxonomy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect a taxonomy page to it's post type archive, you might try something like below.

Careful, though! There's an assumption implicit in your post that a `WP_Taxonomy` has a single `post_type` mapped to it. In practice, you can have your taxonomies map to as many `post_type` objects as you like. The code below redirects taxonomy pages to an associated custom post type archive wether or not it's the only one that taxonomy applies to!

Additionally – make sure that your custom post type's got the `has_archive` key set to true in it's `register_post_type` args!

```
<?php
// functions.php

function redirect_cpt_taxonomy(WP_Query $query) {
    // Get the object of the query. If it's a `WP_Taxonomy`, then you'll be able to check if it's registered to your custom post type!
    $obj = get_queried_object();

    if (!is_admin() // Not admin
        && true === $query->is_main_query() // Not a secondary query
        && true === $query->is_tax() // Is a taxonomy query
    ) {
        $archive_url = get_post_type_archive_link('custom_post_type_name');

        // If the WP_Taxonomy has multiple object_types mapped, and 'custom_post_type' is one of them:
        if (true === is_array($obj->object_type) && true === in_array($obj->object_type, ['custom_post_type_name'])) {
            wp_redirect($archive_url);
            exit;
        }

        // If the WP_Taxonomy has one object_type mapped, and it's 'custom_post_type'
        if (true === is_string($obj->object_type) && 'custom_post_type_name' === $obj->object_type) {
            wp_redirect($archive_url);
            exit;
        }
    }

    // Passthrough, if none of these conditions are met!
    return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'redirect_cpt_taxonomy');
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. And thank you for the warning, I do have a taxonomy that's used for more than one post type.

Comment: Do you know why, when I add the taxonomy on as a query string (eg '?theme=nature') it causes a loop in the redirect?

Comment: My best guess is that it's keeping the query string, somehow. What's the output of doing `var_dump($archive_url);die;` before the redirect?

Comment: OK I see the issue. WP is interpreting my querystring as a call to a taxonomy page and so it's getting stuck in a loop. If I change "theme" to "themex" it works fine. So a bodge is to do that then remove the "x" from my GET result.

Comment: A comment on your very useful options for more than one post type - object_type does not appear in get_queried_object because its the taxonomy object not the post-type object.

Comment: Oh! My bad; I'll have to investigate and update to reflect that.